# Google Maps Android API v2 ClassNotFound Runtime error

Tags: java, android, google-maps, classnotfoundexception, google-maps-android-api-2

EDIT: For those struggling with this, checkout [this link](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw). Follow it carefully, but it does work! The crucial part is using `keytool` to generate your SHA1 hash against your debug keystore. Also, don't forget to add one for release too!

I've been trying to setup Google Maps Android API v2 and after setting everything up as said I'm getting this runtime exception `ClassNotFound`:

```
01-02 16:29:07.927: E/AndroidRuntime(12508): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 16:29:07.927: E/AndroidRuntime(12508): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.MapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
01-02 16:29:07.927: E/AndroidRuntime(12508):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1659)
01-02 16:29:07.927: E/AndroidRuntime(12508):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
01-02 16:29:07.927: E/AndroidRuntime(12508):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
01-02 16:29:07.927: E/AndroidRuntime(12508):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
01-02 16:29:07.927: E/AndroidRuntime(12508):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-02 16:29:07.927: E/AndroidRuntime(12508):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-02 16:29:07.927: E/AndroidRuntime(12508):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
01-02 16:29:07.927: E/AndroidRuntime(12508):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 16:29:07.927: E/AndroidRuntime(12508):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-02 16:29:07.927: E/AndroidRuntime(12508):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
01-02 16:29:07.927: E/AndroidRuntime(12508):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
01-02 16:29:07.927: E/AndroidRuntime(12508):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-02 16:29:07.927: E/AndroidRuntime(12508): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
01-02 16:29:07.927: E/AndroidRuntime(12508):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
01-02 16:29:07.927: E/AndroidRuntime(12508):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
01-02 16:29:07.927: E/AndroidRuntime(12508):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
01-02 16:29:07.927: E/AndroidRuntime(12508):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
01-02 16:29:07.927: E/AndroidRuntime(12508):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
01-02 16:29:07.927: E/AndroidRuntime(12508):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:227)
01-02 16:29:07.927: E/AndroidRuntime(12508):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
01-02 16:29:07.927: E/AndroidRuntime(12508):    at com.example.app.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:11)
01-02 16:29:07.927: E/AndroidRuntime(12508):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-02 16:29:07.927: E/AndroidRuntime(12508):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
01-02 16:29:07.927: E/AndroidRuntime(12508):    ... 11 more
01-02 16:29:07.927: E/AndroidRuntime(12508): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.app-1.apk]
01-02 16:29:07.927: E/AndroidRuntime(12508):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
01-02 16:29:07.927: E/AndroidRuntime(12508):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
01-02 16:29:07.927: E/AndroidRuntime(12508):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
01-02 16:29:07.927: E/AndroidRuntime(12508):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
01-02 16:29:07.927: E/AndroidRuntime(12508):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
01-02 16:29:07.927: E/AndroidRuntime(12508):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
01-02 16:29:07.927: E/AndroidRuntime(12508):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
01-02 16:29:07.927: E/AndroidRuntime(12508):    ... 20 more
```

Has anyone ever come across this before?

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

MapActivity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MapActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Activity needs to extend [FragmentActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) from the support library

Answer (score 2):

Try this code working perfect help full to you.

XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java

```
package com.example.androidmapsv2;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
 final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;
 private GoogleMap myMap;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
   SupportMapFragment mySupportMapFragment 
    = (SupportMapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
   myMap = mySupportMapFragment.getMap();
 } 
@Override
 protected void onResume() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onResume();

  int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

  if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
     "isGooglePlayServicesAvailable SUCCESS", 
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }else{
   GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, RQS_GooglePlayServices);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: I got it working in the end, but it was a lot more simple than this method! Using that code I couldn't get it to show the mapping images, but the controls loaded.

Comment: Actually link which you gave KeTaN refer to the API v1, but question about API v2

Answer (score 1):

Did you run on AVD? if yes try on real devices

Comment: The answer above fixed this, and yes I did read the docs re: AVD ;)